# Why method didDeselectItemAt does not calling?

Tags: uitableview, uikit, cell, uicollectionviewcell, collectionview

I have a problem.
I have a collection view embedded in a tableView.
I store indexPath for selected items (for restoring their state after reusing cell).
The problem is: When I select the item, scroll down and scroll top - my selected item is storing state, but I can not deselect item. Method didDiselectItem does not call.

```
extension CategoryCollectionCell: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        items?.count ?? 0
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: CategoryCell.identefier, for: indexPath) as! CategoryCell
        let currentItem = items?[indexPath.row]
        cell.config(text: currentItem?.name ?? "")
        cell.isSelected = currentItem?.isSelected ?? false
        cell.layoutIfNeeded()
        return cell
    }
}

extension ImmoFilterCategoryCollectionCell: UICollectionViewDelegate {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        items?[indexPath.row].isSelected = true
        delegate?.update(attributes: items, indexPath: self.indexPath)
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        items?[indexPath.row].isSelected = false
        delegate?.update(attributes: items, indexPath: self.indexPath)
    }
}
```

delegate?.update - the method for storing indexPath.

Answer (score 0):

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: Cell, for: indexPath) as! Cell
        guard let currentItem = items?[indexPath.row] else { return cell}
        cell.config(text: currentItem.name )
        if  currentItem.isSelected {
            self.collectionView.selectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .bottom)
            cell.isSelected = true
        }
        return cell
    }
```

It is work for me